# Changing the format of date with month in letters

Tags: r, date, time, format

I have Date and Time column.The main problem is that the year (2016) is not complete in the csv file and OCT is not numeric.

```
Date        Time         rtime
20-Oct-16 14:02:00       20-Oct-16 14:02:00
20-Oct-16 14:02:03       20-Oct-16 14:02:03
```

I want another column called `newtime` with this format

```
newtime
2016-10-20 14:02:00
2016-10-20 14:02:03
```

Any suggestions on how to make the month in a regular number format and making 16 into 2016.

Comment: use dmy_hms(df$rtime) e.g. dmy_hms("20-Oct-16 14:02:00")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lubridate you don't need to specify if the month comes with name (Oct) or as a decimal number (10) or the year is 2016 or 16. Lubridate functions parse heterogeneous date-times formats. For instance:

```
library(lubridate)
df$newtime = dmy_hms(df$rtime) 

       Date     Time              rtime             newtime
1 20-Oct-16 14:02:00 20-Oct-16 14:02:00 2016-10-20 14:02:00
2 20-Oct-16 14:02:03 20-Oct-16 14:02:03 2016-10-20 14:02:03
```

If you use `strptime` then you need to define the format. See ?strptime.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strptime`

```
strptime("20-Oct-16 14:02:00", "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Or `dmy_hms` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::dmy_hms("20-Oct-16 14:02:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `as.POSIXct` with `format`

```
as.POSIXct("20-Oct-16 14:02:00", format = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2016-10-20 14:02:00 IST"
```